# UWP Application Button Holding

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I developed an UWP application and here is my button control:

```
 <Button x:Name="Reversebutton" Content="Reverse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="180" Height="130" PointerReleased="Reversebutton_PointerReleased" ClickMode="Press"
                Background="Green" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
                FocusVisualMargin="-50,-50,-50,-50" IsHoldingEnabled="False" PointerMoved="Reversebutton_PointerEntered" PointerEntered="Reversebutton_PointerEntered"
                PointerExited="Reversebutton_PointerReleased" />
```

I am using windows Iot and RP3 and 7" official hdmi touche screen

The issue I am having is if the user clicks on a button but then drags their finger over the the button next to the one they click on the buttoon go into a hold mode and I am trying to disable that.

I though the IsHoldingEnabled="False" would fix the issue but it still happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure my understanding is right. Did you mean that when pressing  button A and keeping pressed,  at the same time dragging another button B to the pressed button A, the button A fires the holding event? If it is right, you may try to change the [ManipulationModes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationModes) of the target UI element.

Comment: Yes that is correct while pressing A and their finger goes to button B, button A will stay on as if it was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [GestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer) class to change the behavior. You can enable or disable gesture settings for Tap,**Hold**,RightTap,CrossSlide and other interaction. Please refer to the UWP sample([BasicInput](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput)).